# Passing data from one Form to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms in one of my projects. In form1 I have a dataGridView and In form2 I have 4 TextBoxes.
in Form1, I want to get a value in a variable from a datagridview using CellMouseClick event and then pass it to a TextBox in Form2

I have tried this.

form1 # it give me an Error

```
public form(int id)
{
    int x;
    x = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

and what iam suppose to do in the form2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx) you can [construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx) a type with the given prerequisites for [construction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx).

If that means an integer, then so be it:

```
public MyForm(int id) {
  SomeIdProperty = id;
}
```

And instead of `var form = new MyForm();`, do:

```
var form = new MyForm(idOfTheRelevantThing);
```

*Then* show it.

Comment: and how can i call it from another form

Answer (score 4):

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm2 = new Form2(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are showing the `Form2` from `Form1`, you can pass the value using the constructor. Something like this:

```
class Form2 {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Form2(string value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Form2_Load() {
        textBox1.Text = Value;
    }
}
```

and do this (inside `Form1.cs`):

```
Form2 f = new Form2("the value here");
f.ShowDialog(); //or f.Show();
```