# go to next form without losing the data that is already entered in the form (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Is there any other way to go to the next form besides using `form2 frm2=new form2();`?

i have created previous buttons for my forms with this code:
first form:

```
userform3 form3 = new userform3();
```

with:

```
form3.Show();
this.Hide();
form3.Hide();
form3.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

second form:`this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`

this works perfectly but when i enter data in the second form and i click on `previous` button and then when click on`next`when i'm in first form to go back to second form the datas i have entered in second form are all gone,i think the problem is with `form2 frm2=new form2()` ,is there a way to resolve this?
thanks for the help

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your problem. You have two forms and the data is not kept from one to another? Anyway bear in mind that setting the form's `DialogResult`will proceed closing it afterwards.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100552/passing-data-from-one-form-to-another#15100590

Comment: You can store the Details in the Global Variable.

Comment: @SH7 do you have the codes for that? thanks

Comment: If you don't want to close the form don't do it. If you want to persist data do it. If you want help try to pick less confusing numbering!

Comment: @joseph Refer https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-make-global-variable-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

you must call .show method like this this code 
and you must create object out of show method and hide method

```
secForm sf = new secForm();

public void showSecForm(Window form)
{
form.Show();
}

public void hideSecForm(Window form)
{
form.Hide();
}
```

and if you want to create new form (if want all data reset) 
do like this code

```
sf=new secForm();
```

and you will be use this methods like this codes in your button

```
public void ButtonShow_Click(event e ,....)
{
 showSecForm(sf);
 this.Hide();
}
```

**Tip** : when you use `new` it will create new form with empty data like this code

```
Form f1= new Form();
```